# SystemVerilog input signal being Z extended

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, hardware, hdl

I've been using Verilog and SystemVerilog for many years, but I just came across something which seems weird.

I don't know if it's something I just never noticed or if there is something special about this I am missing.

Basically I have a module which has a 16-bit input, to which I connected an 8-bit signal. This seems like no big deal to me, in fact it's one of the things I love about Verilog/SystemVerilog, since unlike VHDL, you are allowed to do things like that.

I would expect the signal connected to the input port of my module to be right-aligned and zero-padded on the left, but instead it is being padded with Zs.

That causes my simulation to not work, because for example I use that signal to initialize a counter after substracting one from it, which leads XXXX.

Is this behaviour expected? Can I change something in my code to get the behaviour I expected?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems reasonable.  I ran a simulation on several simulators on EDA Playground, and I got a mix of results: some had the MSBs as 0, others had them as `z`.

The best approach is to explicitly drive the inputs with the value you desire.  For example, if you want the MSBs to be 0, use something like:

```
module tb;
    reg [7:0] data;
    // ...
    dut i1 ({ {8{1'b0}}, data });
endmodule
```

This creates a 16-bit expression which is connected to the module input port.  The expression is a concatenation of an 8-bit constant and the 8-bit data signal.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a size mismatch happening in your design or testbench, there should be a warning (if not an error) raised from your compiler/simulation tool. There is no default behavior defined to pad with 0 or undriven z, therefore it can be 0-padded or unknown depending on your tool, and you are on your own risk. The best practice is to watch carefully if there is such warning/error already reported, and try to resolve it during compilation/elaboration phase, or better to run a linting tool before compilation.